# Distance between from one point to another point on map with the help of Location

Tags: android

In My app,i am using map and want to get the distance between from one place to another place by the help of Location. and i am getting location of every point when change the location.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo%28android.location.Location%29

Comment: There is literally a `distanceTo()` method in `Location`. _Please_ check the docs or a search engine in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give `source` and `destination` `lat` `long` and calculate distance in km.

```
 public static double  getDistance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
        int R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
        double dLat = deg2rad(lat2 - lat1);  // deg2rad below
        double dLon = deg2rad(lon2 - lon1);
        double a =
                Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
                        Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) *
                                Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
        double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
        double d = R * c; // Distance in km
        return d;
    }

   public static double  deg2rad(double deg) {
        return deg * (Math.PI / 180);
    }
```